# How to get a token from string with multiple combination

Tags: java

I have a string with multiple combinations like below.

```
    msqlora -sn $(PWF_pdmm8107)
    msqlora -n $(PWF_pdmm8107)
    msqlora  $(PWF_pdmm8107)
```

the string is single. but at runtime, it may be formed any one of the above situation.

I want to retrieve $(PWF_pdmm8107) token from a string.

What I have done till now.

```
while ( st.hasMoreTokens() )
{
  if ( st.nextToken().equals( "-sn" ) )
  {
    pwf = st.nextToken();
  }
}
```

please suggest a way so I can retrieve $(PWF_pdmm8107) from above string combination.

Thanks

Comment: Does the String you are trying to retrieve ever change or is it always the exact same?

Answer (score 1):

One way you could do this is to `split()` the string into an array using a space as a delimiter, and select the last element

```
String input = "msqlora -sn $(PWF_pdmm8107)";
String[] tmp = input.split(" ");
String output = tmp[tmp.length - 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the answer if regex is allowed..
`"(\\$\\(.*\\))"`

```
 String str = "msqlora -sn $(PWF_pdmm8107)\n" +
"    msqlora -n $(PWF_pdmm8107)\n" +
"    msqlora  $(PWF_pdmm8107)";
    Pattern compile = Pattern.compile("(\\$\\(.*\\))");
            Matcher match = compile.matcher(str);
           while( match.find())
           {
               System.out.println(match.group());
           }
```

Output:-

```
$(PWF_pdmm8107)
$(PWF_pdmm8107)
$(PWF_pdmm8107)
```